# Virus not in "anti virus" with solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a problem, I need to query solr with a weak not (- sign)
For example I want documents that contains virus but I don't care about anti virus.
A query like: virus -"anti virus", will remove documents that may contain virus and "anti virus" but I want to remove only documents that contains only "anti virus" without virus.

Please note the virus - "anti virus" is just an example it can be any word and phrase that contains that word.

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a number of scenarios here and if you absolutely need to find documents that contains "virus" only when standalone and not marked by other words, you need to do some index-time processing, perhaps replacing "anti virus" with anti_virus or some other non-matching combination. That assumes you know what the combinations are during indexing.

An easier way would be to say that you want to show all documents but you want to upgrade those containing standalone "virus" term. Or more specifically downgrade those containing the "anti virus" combined term. So, the documents containing only "virus" terms would come on top, followed by those containing both standalone and combined terms and then followed by those containing only combined terms. This can be achieved with:

> virus "anti virus"^-10

^ is a boost here, and you give it negative values. So, any matching compound term would push the document down in the ranking.

Comment: Do negative boosts work properly now (and in what version did it change)? And with which query parses? The [Lucene ticket is still open](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-4378).

Comment: I am basing this on Ref Guide and a quick test with 7.5. http://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_0/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html#using-negative-boost 
I am not entirely sure when it was introduced. On the other hand, perhaps this would be broken again in LUCENE-7996 (Solr 8) or at least not work as well. So, maybe there is a better answer than mine.

Comment: Neat! The guide above is for 8, so it should work there as well. The other option is to use a boost of all documents not matching the negative boost.